# Detecting if an 1-dimenisional distribution is Multimodal

Tags: optimization, bimodal, multimodality

I'm writing up some C++ code for one of my Master's coursework. What I'm actually doing at the moment isn't on the syllabus, but I wish to implement it anyway as it will allow me to produce my own memetic computing algorithm.

Onwards!

I have four different optimisation problems coded up in C++:

- Michalewicz [-512, 512] - meant to be larger
- Schwefel    [-5.12, 5.12]
- Rastigin    [-5.12, 5.12]
- Sphere      [-5.12, 5.12]

I know from using these that the only problem which isn't multimodal is Sphere, as it only has one global minima and maxima, but the other three problems are riddled with local minima and local maxima.

My question is, where `n` = the dimensionality of the problem, I'm trying to produce a statistical test which tells the computer if the current optimisation problem is multimodal by taking a 1D slice (line). Depending on the output the program then selects a pool of operators (single solution or population-based optimisers) to attempt to find the global minima.

The first thing I did was to develop a distribution (in 1D) using the bounds of the problem. When I output these distributions in Excel the charts I get are what I expected. Next, I found this following paper:
http://www.i3.psychologie.uni-wuerzburg.de/fileadmin/06020300/user_upload/Janczyk/pfister_et_al_2013_bimodality.pdf

They use Skewness and Kurtosis to find something called a `bimodality coefficient`. Now, I'm not able to reproduce these results in C++ as I suspect Matlab has some trickery in terms of how they compute Kurtosis, so my results states that every problem except Michalewicz is multimodal (Which is not correct!!)

Here's some data (1D lines from the optimisation prolem):

**Sphere**

> 25.2004
>   24.2064
>   23.2324
>   22.2784
>   21.3444
>   20.4304
>   19.5364
>   18.6624
>   17.8084
>   16.9744
>   16.1604
>   15.3664
>   14.5924
>   13.8384
>   13.1044
>   12.3904
>   11.6964
>   11.0224
>   10.3684
>   9.7344
>   9.1204
>   8.5264
>   7.9524
>   7.3984
>   6.8644
>   6.3504
>   5.8564
>   5.3824
>   4.9284
>   4.4944
>   4.0804
>   3.6864
>   3.3124
>   2.9584
>   2.6244
>   2.3104
>   2.0164
>   1.7424
>   1.4884
>   1.2544
>   1.0404
>   0.8464
>   0.6724
>   0.5184
>   0.3844
>   0.2704
>   0.1764
>   0.1024
>   0.0484
>   0.0144
>   0.0004
>   0.0064
>   0.0324
>   0.0784
>   0.1444
>   0.2304
>   0.3364
>   0.4624
>   0.6084
>   0.7744
>   0.9604
>   1.1664
>   1.3924
>   1.6384
>   1.9044
>   2.1904
>   2.4964
>   2.8224
>   3.1684
>   3.5344
>   3.9204
>   4.3264
>   4.7524
>   5.1984
>   5.6644
>   6.1504
>   6.6564
>   7.1824
>   7.7284
>   8.2944
>   8.8804
>   9.4864
>   10.1124
>   10.7584
>   11.4244
>   12.1104
>   12.8164
>   13.5424
>   14.2884
>   15.0544
>   15.8404
>   16.6464
>   17.4724
>   18.3184
>   19.1844
>   20.0704
>   20.9764
>   21.9024
>   22.8484
>   23.8144
>   24.8004
>   25.8064
>   26.8324

**Rastign**

> 15.08054031
>   12.44916322
>   5.634081898
>   -2.300742733
>   -8.269711697
>   -10.34815318
>   -8.356811024
>   -3.688270535
>   1.463148257
>   5.084118795
>   6.111823406
>   4.702612168
>   1.955348819
>   -0.719244438
>   -2.263010207
>   -2.371550982
>   -1.486566652
>   -0.435316748
>   0.069031276
>   -0.193614067
>   -0.872664091
>   -1.291325524
>   -0.871825677
>   0.487491228
>   2.285754028
>   3.620821814
>   3.631064359
>   1.966078457
>   -0.950323075
>   -4.013409675
>   -5.872922186
>   -5.532649855
>   -2.84744159
>   1.319464265
>   5.376581008
>   7.628965207
>   6.996082011
>   3.515915078
>   -1.594914797
>   -6.375268028
>   -8.888950878
>   -8.021360826
>   -3.97149892
>   1.776674672
>   7.009470734
>   9.652879198
>   8.608486302
>   4.214193116
>   -1.86474389
>   -7.279189126
>   -9.920750167
>   -8.757458438
>   -4.243997667
>   1.859122451
>   7.184423204
>   9.692563786
>   8.468277233
>   4.060912571
>   -1.759810354
>   -6.725172969
>   -8.968320054
>   -7.740942689
>   -3.66493783
>   1.5668076
>   5.90143842
>   7.748018971
>   6.575454804
>   3.056073443
>   -1.280114189
>   -4.713219557
>   -6.031660538
>   -4.97181358
>   -2.23431941
>   0.89973012
>   3.160516381
>   3.819244754
>   2.930019015
>   1.199675732
>   -0.425655394
>   -1.243328891
>   -1.11077162
>   -0.450071111
>   0.047857592
>   -0.142109989
>   -1.038342913
>   -2.093758866
>   -2.468030134
>   -1.508280562
>   0.803566029
>   3.68449903
>   5.794346702
>   5.824284718
>   3.181593178
>   -1.558712727
>   -6.695139462
>   -9.990991888
>   -9.618692643
>   -5.06779544
>   2.407550082
>   10.07026421
>   14.68369443
>   13.85125391
>   7.166887347

**Schwfel**

> 422.9184972
>   422.9076247
>   422.8927192
>   422.8737881
>   422.8508422
>   422.8238953
>   422.7929647
>   422.7580711
>   422.7192389
>   422.6764964
>   422.629876
>   422.5794143
>   422.5251525
>   422.4671364
>   422.4054168
>   422.34005
>   422.2710974
>   422.1986267
>   422.1227115
>   422.0434322
>   421.9608762
>   421.8751381
>   421.7863207
>   421.6945352
>   421.5999018
>   421.5025505
>   421.4026219
>   421.3002676
>   421.1956518
>   421.0889518
>   420.9803594
>   420.8700826
>   420.7583466
>   420.6453961
>   420.5314975
>   420.4169416
>   420.3020464
>   420.1871613
>   420.072672
>   419.9590062
>   419.8466416
>   419.7361161
>   419.6280413
>   419.5231219
>   419.4221833
>   419.3262139
>   419.2364339
>   419.1544183
>   419.0823469
>   419.0236428
>   418.985719
>   418.9605731
>   418.908803
>   418.841556
>   418.7632086
>   418.6763193
>   418.582663
>   418.4835824
>   418.3801483
>   418.273245
>   418.1636217
>   418.0519244
>   417.9387187
>   417.8245048
>   417.7097296
>   417.5947946
>   417.4800631
>   417.3658653
>   417.2525023
>   417.14025
>   417.0293614
>   416.9200693
>   416.8125885
>   416.707117
>   416.6038377
>   416.5029199
>   416.4045202
>   416.3087835
>   416.2158439
>   416.1258254
>   416.0388428
>   415.9550021
>   415.8744013
>   415.7971304
>   415.7232727
>   415.6529044
>   415.5860955
>   415.52291
>   415.4634062
>   415.4076369
>   415.3556499
>   415.3074884
>   415.2631906
>   415.2227907
>   415.1863185
>   415.1538
>   415.1252573
>   415.1007092
>   415.0801707
>   415.0636539
>   415.0511674
>   415.0427172
>   415.0383061

I'm not entirely sure on what to attempt to far. I've had a look at techniques on Wikipedia, but I'm unsure on how I'm supposed to implement them. For example, Ashman's D algorithm uses two different means and standard deviations? I can't see how this would help me with my problem.

Thanks

Comment: very hard problem ...

Comment: I suspected so!

Comment: I reckon I may be able to solve this by calculating the amount of slope sign changes. I'll update this later with an answer if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to calculate if my problem is multi-modal or not by calculating the amount of slope sign changes. What I mean by this is, if the slope goes from a positive, to a negative then this indicates the slope has changed. If this occurs more than twice, then we have a local maxima / minima.

This is the definition of a slope sign change

```
X = x2 - x1
Y = y2 - y1
Slope = Y / X
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan, I am not sure if I completely understand your problem so please correct me if I am wrong.

1. You want to construct a statistical test to see if the data in a simple random sample come from a particular population distribution;
2. The reason that you wish to do this is that you want to tell your program which optimization algorithm to find a maximum or minimum for an objective function;
3. The objective function is proportional to a probability mass function and the sample is drawn by generating random numbers and plugging these into the objective function.

Is this roughly correct? You want to use a random number generator to have a peek at the objective function before deciding which algorithm to use? The goal I suspect is to minimize computation time and find the global optimum of this objective function?

One way forward that I would suggest is to define what you could call a peak or a trough in terms of what proportion of values of this sample from the objective function are higher or lower than x % of the values in the sample and to compute the distance (e.g. the euclidean distance) between the coordinates of these highest and lowest values. The coordinates are the random numbers that you used to generate the value of the objective function. If these are more than [y] units away from each other then these are different peaks or troughs. Else not.

I don't think that you need a statistical test if I understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I don't think you're on the correct lines.

I have four optimisation problems, where each problem has a boundary. I create a distribution by iterating through the boundary at an increment of 0.1, and then I compute the optimisation function.

This is the Rastign Problem:

http://www-optima.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/member/student/hedar/Hedar_files/TestGO_files/Page2607.htm

I'm taking a 1D slice from it. From this slice, I want to be able to see if the distribution is multimodal, or not.

Comment: Ah okay, then I think I misunderstood you. My bad. Essentially you're taking a picture of a landscape and want to know whether you can say something about that landscape based on that picture?

Comment: Yeah in a way. It may or may not have many peaks / troughs, and I want to find out via some means if it's multimodal, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Jonathan Brown and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418461/calculate-the-modes-in-a-multimodal-distribution-in-r), i made some code with explanations for completeness.

The goal is to find how many modes there are in a distribution

```
# dataIn <- "Use some data from the original question"
densHere <- density(dataIn, kernel = "gaussian", n = 1024*10)
slope = vector("numeric")
for (i in 2:length(densHere$"x")) {

    X = densHere$x[i] - densHere$x[i - 1] 
    Y = densHere$y[i] - densHere$y[i - 1]

    slope = c(slope, Y / X)
}

numberOfModes <- length(which(diff(sign(slope)) == -2))  # Now find only the slopes from positive to negative
```

Alternatively use splines to do the trick:

```
densitySpline <- smooth.spline(densHere$x, densHere$y, all.knots = TRUE, spar = 0.8)
s.0 <- predict(densitySpline, densitySpline$x, deriv = 0)  # Fit the density
s.1 <- predict(densitySpline, densitySpline$x, deriv = 1)  # Get the derivative of the fit
numberOfModes <- which(diff(sign(s.1$y)) == -2)
```

**EDIT:**

I probably came late to the party. The slope approach is unfortunately very much dependent to the smoothing done by the kernel. You will have to toy a lot with the parameters of `density` function.

**EDIT 2:**

While researching for the problem, i came across **Dip Test**. In `R` the package is called `diptest`. My result contains multimodal distributions and it finds nearly almost all of them, while not suffering from the usual problem of large sample size.